# Issue with Expo Speech for Urdu language on iOS

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm encountering an issue with Expo Speech while attempting to use Urdu language on iOS. While English text-to-speech works fine, I'm experiencing difficulties with Urdu text-to-speech.

### I'm using Expo Speech library for text-to-speech functionality in my React Native app.
The English text-to-speech feature works as expected on both Android and iOS platforms.
However, when attempting to use Urdu text for speech synthesis on iOS, I encounter [specific error message or undesired behavior].
I've ensured that the text is correctly formatted and passed to the Expo Speech API.
I've checked the Expo Speech documentation and couldn't find explicit support for Urdu language on iOS.
Details:

- I'm using Expo Speech library for text-to-speech functionality in my React Native app.
- The English text-to-speech feature works as expected on both Android and iOS platforms.
- However, when attempting to use Urdu text for speech synthesis on iOS.
- I've ensured that the text is correctly formatted and passed to the Expo Speech API.
- I've checked the Expo Speech documentation and couldn't find explicit support for Urdu language on iOS.